# How do I figure out what -O<num> options do in gcc?

Tags: optimization, gcc, flags

I seem to remember being able to print out (or locate) the specific switches that each -O<num> option turns on.  Can you remind?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [list of new features on gcc 4.3](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.3/changes.html) shows a way to do it, via an extension to the `--help` command line option:

```
gcc -c -Q -O3 --help=optimizers > /tmp/O3-opts
gcc -c -Q -O2 --help=optimizers > /tmp/O2-opts
diff /tmp/O2-opts /tmp/O3-opts | grep enabled
```

Note, however that I never tried that, only read about it. The documentation about this command line option is at http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html#Overall-Options

If you ever read the list of new features on gcc 4.3, perhaps this was what you were recalling.

Answer (score 2):

You may also try the good ol' manual

```
$ man gcc
```

at the subsection "Options That Control Optimization".

Answer (score 0):

On many machines, '`info gcc`' will produce a wealth of information.  Using '`gcc -v --help`' produced a very long listing of options from sub-processes (actually, 1001 lines on stdout, and 14 on stderr) on my Mac (PPC G4 and MacOS X 10.4.11).